# Prevent new packages from linking start up scripts?

Tags: package-management, init, init.d

How can i prevent newly installed packages from creating links in e.g `/etc/rc2.d`?
Currently i'm launching `update-rc.d -f blabla remove /etc/rc.local` each time during boot.

But this shouldn't be necessary.

I need this because i have some packages , like samba server , no need to start everytime , just start whenever i need it is fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing the links, disable them. The difference is that removal does not make `dpkg` aware of your preference to prevent the startup scripts from being executed because `dpkg` runs `update-rc.d` too for removing and adding the links.

To disable a service:

```
sudo update-rc.d blabla disable
```

You should not have a need for removing `/etc/rc.local` as it's usually not modified by package management scripts.