# Nginx - disable autostart

Tags: autostart, nginx

I went through some manuals and I didn't understand yet. How do I disable autostart nginx service?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Try this command:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f nginx disable
```

Comment: I tried `sudo update-rc.d -f nginx disable`. What is the difference between them?

Comment: The difference is that `disable` is better! :) You got me. It effectively 'makes `dpkg` aware of your preference to prevent the startup scripts from being executed (because `dpkg` runs update-rc.d too)'. Credit to @Lekensteyn for [the explanation](http://askubuntu.com/a/63511/40421).

Comment: I already run `disable` and then `remove`. How can I undo it?

Comment: Umm.. You want to enable autostart now?

Comment: I want to undo remove. And then call disable again if necessary.

Comment: `sudo update-rc.d nginx defaults; sudo update-rc.d -f nginx disable`

Comment: Apparently does not works on Ubunu 20.10.

Answer (score 62):

**Update:**
I made changes to supports more distributions:

use this:

```
sudo systemctl disable nginx
```

It will disable it and if you like to stop running service use this:

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx
```

works on Ubuntu and any Systemd based distributions

Comment: it works on ububut 18.04 as well

Comment: If you're going to use systemd style, use it for everything, don't have some weird mashup of using the `service` shim for some commands. That second one should just be `sudo systemctl stop nginx`.

Comment: Also works on ububut 20.10 as well

Comment: This approach is better.